# CSS remove styling specified in the tag in a media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

In the HTML Code (which I can't modify) there's a div with style specified in the tag. But I don't want this style to apply in a specific media query for responsive purposes.

```
<div style="width:calc((100% - var(--column-spacing) * 1) * 0.4375);margin-inline-start:var(--column-spacing)"></div>
```

I tried to just put another value in the media query for this div but it doesn't work. Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important` to the styles should work since it overrides the styles set in the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `!important` property in the css to override the inline css as shown below

```
selector {
  property: value; /* normal declaration */
  property: value !important; /* important declaration (standard) */
  property: value ! important; /* important declaration (non-standard) */
}
```

Nevertheless it is recommended to use it as sparingly as possible

Comment: since it works do you mind marking my reply as the answer?